# THREEJS: Individual geometry shades particularly

Tags: three.js, shadow

i have very particular geometry build with three.js Geomtry, using faces. The geometry represents the top side of a picture frame. My problem is, that the Geometry shades only some faces on the floor. With plane or cube, i don't have this problem.

http://postimg.org/image/xy1p2cmg1/

On the image you will see 2 black "things", these a two differently sized picture frames having their own complex vertice+face structure throwing only partly a shadow. Especially the inside faces dont throw the shadow, so the shadow is empty inside. I got some problems to color the MeshPhongMaterials, but that shouldn't be part of this question here. Even if the pictures here are not clear, because the geometry is black, but i am sure the faces close the whole geometry.

Here is the same scene with wireframe:

http://postimg.org/image/44uotqxsx/

The code looks like that here:

```
// Lights
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xFFD073, 3, 2000, Math.PI/3, 10 );        // hex, intensity, distance, angle, exponent
spotLight.position.set( 100, 1700, 100 );

spotLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
spotLight.castShadow = true;

spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 2048;
spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 2048;
spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 25;
spotLight.shadowCameraFar = 4000;
spotLight.shadowCameraFov = 50;

spotLight.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
spotLight.shadowBias = -0.0002;

scene.add( spotLight );


// build geometry from vertices and faces
function buildGeometry(vertices, faces) {
    var geo = new THREE.Geometry();

    //vertices
    for(var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( vertices[i][0], vertices[i][1], vertices[i][2] ) );
    }

    //faces
    for(var j = 0; j < faces.length; j++) {
        if(faces[j].length == 3) {
            geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( faces[j][0], faces[j][1], faces[j][2] ) );
        } else if(faces[j].length == 4) {
            geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face4( faces[j][0], faces[j][1], faces[j][2], faces[j][3] ) );
        } else {
            console.error(j + " face has " + faces[j].length + ", but needs 3 or 4 faces vertices");
        }
        geo.faces[j].color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
    }

    return geo;
}


// create the frame side
this.___frame_top = new THREE.Object3D();

// Note: position and rotation is done somewhere else...

// frame side 1
var geo_frame_side = buildGeometry(side_vertices, side_faces);
this.___frame_top.___frame_side = new THREE.Mesh( geo_frame_side, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({vertexColors: 0x439812, wireframe: wireframe}) );
this.___frame_top.___frame_side.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

// frame edge 1
var geo_edge_1 = buildGeometry(edge_vertices, edge_faces);
this.___frame_top.___frame_edge_1 = new THREE.Mesh( geo_edge_1, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({colors: 0x439812, wireframe: wireframe}) );
this.___frame_top.___frame_edge_1.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

// frame edge 2
var geo_edge_2 = buildGeometry(edge_vertices, edge_faces);
this.___frame_top.___frame_edge_2 = new THREE.Mesh( geo_edge_2, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({colors: 0x439812, wireframe: wireframe}) );
this.___frame_top.___frame_edge_2.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
this.___frame_top.___frame_edge_2.rotation.y = Math.PI;

// shadow
this.___frame_top.castShadow = true;
this.___frame_top.receiveShadow = true;
this.___frame_top.___frame_side.receiveShadow = true;
this.___frame_top.___frame_side.castShadow = true;
this.___frame_top.___frame_edge_1.receiveShadow = true;
this.___frame_top.___frame_edge_1.castShadow = true;
this.___frame_top.___frame_edge_2.receiveShadow = true;
this.___frame_top.___frame_edge_2.castShadow = true;

// put all together
this.___frame_top.add(this.___frame_top.___frame_side);
this.___frame_top.add(this.___frame_top.___frame_edge_1);
this.___frame_top.add(this.___frame_top.___frame_edge_2);

scene.add(this.___frame_top);
```

What can cause this shadow issue? I guess its not a bug in threejs, probably i miss something of the deeper mechanics of the code and shader?

Help very appreciated!

Comment: After more research, i begin to suspect that the problem rises from faces having normals pointing inside the geometry. When i used `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;` i thought this would also fix the shading problem, but it seems that DoubleSide only affects to avoid backface culling.

Comment: I would remove the `THREE.DoubleSide` and push the faces in different order. You are pushing Face3( 0, 1, 2 ), so change it to Face3( 0, 2, 1 ) and change the Face4, to Face4( 0, 3, 2, 1 ).

Comment: @gaitat: interesting, that changed the normals! I wonder whats the logic behind the order... need more research :)

Comment: Vertex ordering (clockwise or counter-clockwise) specifies the normal direction.

Comment: Yes, thats what i found too. Thanks Gailat, you made my mind up! Unfortunately my face definition is messed, because its hand-written. So simply turning the order while building the face won't do it. I have to fix the order by hand. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If some comment was useful, I would appreciate an up vote. Up arrow on the left of the comment. You have to move your mouse there to see the arrows.

Comment: I would like to up-vote, but unfortunately i seem by myself not to have enough reputation yet to do so. Maybe you can upvote my question and i get a point in order to be able. Dont know if that will be enough of points... Otherwise, why dont you set an answer, that i can accept?